# How do I access the name of a list in a function?

Tags: programming

Background:

```
  bar := {1, 1, 1};
  foo[var_] := {Hold[var], 2 var}
  SetAttributes[foo, HoldAll]
  foo[bar]
```

Result, as expected:

```
  {Hold[bar], {2, 2, 2}}
```

What I then do ( which is clearly not correct, but I don't know another way ) is that I `ToString` the first element of the list, i.e. `Hold[bar]` and then extract the substring "bar" out of it.

What I want is just this:

```
  f[data_?VectorQ] := f[data, name_of_data]
  f[data_?VectorQ, name_?StringQ] := "Save data as name" ...
```

So for example:

```
   ape = {1,2,3};
   bear= {2,3,4};
   f[ape] translates to f[{1,2,3"}, "ape"]
   f[bear, "bird"] translates to f[{2,3,4}, "bird"]
   f[ape+bear] translates to Null or False.
```

**Question: How do I access the name of a list in a function ?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `HoldForm` instead of `Hold`.

```
Clear@f
SetAttributes[f, HoldAll]
f[data_?VectorQ] := f[data, ToString@HoldForm@data]
f[data_?VectorQ, name_?StringQ] := "Save data as " <> name
```

With this:

```
f[ape]
(* "Save data as ape" *)

f[ape, "bird"]
(* "Save data as bird" *)
```

To get `Null` or `False` for `f[ape+bear]`, you can use `StringFreeQ[name, "+"]` to see if the input is of that form. Similarly, `"{"` for list arguments (no need to check for `"}"`). So the second definition for `f` above would be:

```
f[data_?VectorQ, name_?StringQ] := 
    If[StringFreeQ[name, "+" | "{"], "Save data as " <> name, False]

f[{1, 2, 3}]
(* False *)

f[ape + bear]
(* False *)
```

Comment: Hmm, 4 seconds difference

Comment: Oooh. That's the closest I've been involved in! :)

Comment: Any reason for `name_?StringQ` rather than `name_String`?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard That's what the OP used for whatever reason and I stuck with it

Comment: @R.M.: I think you need `_?StringQ` since _String would not work due to the `HoldAll` attribute. You could alternatively wrap an `Evaluate` around the second argument in the call to `f` which would probably a good idea anyway...

Comment: @Albert This is why I ask these questions.  I forgot that.

Comment: @AlbertRetey Ah, thanks! I completely forgot about that too.

Answer (score 8):

You could use `HoldForm` instead of `Hold`, for example

```
bar := {1, 1, 1};
foo[var_] := {ToString@HoldForm[var], var}
SetAttributes[foo, HoldAll]
foo[bar]

(* output: {"bar", {1, 1, 1}} *)
```

**Edit**

To distinguish between proper variable names and something like `ape + bear` you could do something like

```
foo[var_] := {var, Quiet@Check[SymbolName[Unevaluated[var]], False]}
SetAttributes[foo, HoldAll]

bar := {1, 1, 1};
ape = {2, 3, 4};

foo[bar]

(* ==> {{1, 1, 1}, "bar"} *)

foo[bar + ape]

(* ==> {{3, 4, 5}, False} *)
```

Comment: Is there a smart way to check that only f[varname] is OK and not f[{1,2,3}] or f[var1+var2+var3] etc.? they all pass VectorQ

Comment: @ndroock1 I've updated my answer

Comment: As for the check whether the argument is a symbol you could just use `foo[var_Symbol]:=...` or even combine it with `_?VectorQ` as this: `_Symbol?VectorQ`. It might come as a surprise that this works but `_Symbol` will check the `Head` of the unevaluated argument due to the `HoldAll` attribute while the `VectorQ` will see the evaluated argument. And yes, Leonid would for sure consider the `_?VectorQ` part to be an evaluation leak. For this particular use case I would consider that no problem though...