# Passing unquoted strings (poor man's enumeration)

Tags: function-construction, options

I would like to be able to pass an unquoted string as a parameter to a Mathematica function [that I am writing] and have it show up without evaluation if the string happens to be defined. Thus I would like

```
Clear["Global`*"]
f[x_] := Print[ToString[x]];
f[Middle] (* prints the string Middle *)
Middle = 3
f[Middle] (* prints the string Middle *)
```

Obviously this cannot work the way I've written it. Yet it is legal to write

```
Plot[g[x],{x,0,3}, PlotStyle->Black]
```

and `Black` happens to be a protected variable, so it will never be defined.

How can I emulate, or come close to emulating, this behavior. I'm willing to put up with some compromises in the function invocation syntax (in particular, the option syntax opt->Middle would be fine).

Apologies if this is somewhere in the docs. I couldn't find it...

Thanks.

Addendum: While J.M.'s solution answers the question I posed above, I would also like the following to work:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
SetAttributes[foo,HoldAll];
foo[x_] := Print[ToString[Unevaluated[x]]];
Table[foo[i],{i,{a,b,c}}] (* prints {i,i,i}, as expected *)
Table[foo[Evaluate[i]], {i,{a,b,c}}] (* prints {a,b,c} as expected *)
a = 3
Table[foo[Evaluate[i]], {i,{a,b,c}}] (* prints {3,b,c} *)
```

I would like the last line to print {a,b,c} just like the one before it - that is, I'd like `i` evaluated only once. Am I asking too much?

For context: this is part of a larger function that computes something, but does so in different ways depending on the setting of a mode parameter. I want to be able to pass in that mode parameter without evaluation; hence the original question. But I also want to be able to invoke the function inside a Table function as above. Here's a simple example:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
SetAttributes[foo,HoldAll];
foo[x_] := Block[{z=ToString[Unevaluated[x]]}, If[x == "square", x^2, x+1]];
Table[Integrate[foo[Evaluate[i]],{x,0,3}],{i,{"square", "xyzzy"}}];
    {9, 45/2}
a=3
Table[Integrate[foo[Evaluate[i]],{x,0,3}],{i,{"square", "xyzzy"}}];
    {45/2, 45/2}
```

since in the second invocation the parameter to foo has the value 3, not the value a. How can I achieve both of these behaviors?

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5187/5

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
SetAttributes[f, HoldAll];
f[x_] := Print[ToString[Unevaluated[x]]]
```

Now, try `Middle = 3; f[Middle]`.

Comment: I was aboooout to post the same. +1

Comment: That should work fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

You may want to use the attribute `HoldAllComplete` to avoid the `Orderless` property of `Times`, allowing multiple-word strings:

```
SetAttributes[func, HoldAllComplete]
func[stuff___] := ToString[Unevaluated[stuff]]

func[this is a string without quotes]
```

> ```
> "this is a string without quotes"
> ```

Lower level syntax rules are still parsed however, so this is only safe with alphanumeric words:

```
func[this is @ a @ string // without quotes]
```

> ```
> "(without quotes)[this is[a[string]]]"
> ```

---

Regarding your updated question you should almost certainly be using indexed variables (`DownValues`).  See [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6514/121) for reference.

Your attempt:

```
a = 3

Table[foo[Evaluate[i]], {i,{a,b,c}}] (* prints {3,b,c} *)
```

Cannot work, as `a` evaluates to `3` before `Table` assigns it to `i` (using a mechanism similar to `Block`).  Consider:

```
a := Print["!"]

Table[Abort[], {i, {a, b, c}}]
```

> ```
> During evaluation of In[]:= !
>
> Out[]= $Aborted
> ```

As you can see the `Print` evaluates before the body.

If you have advance knowledge of the symbol names you could use `Block` (but IMHO this entire process is inadvisable):

```
Block[{a},
 Table[ToString[i], {i, {a, b, c}}]
]
```