# How to parse string to expression?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, string-manipulation, expression-manipulation, expression-construction

When trying to make a string an expression I see some wrong results:

```
str = "one Test String to see"
(* "one Test String to see" *)

str //ToExpression
(* one see String Test to *)
```

What is the correct way to do that to avoid the mess up?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I am expecting to have following output:

```
one Test String to see
```

**UPDATE 1**

As  @ Mr.Wizard said

```
ToExpression[str, StandardForm, HoldForm]
```

Does what I want. Now if I have two strings (lot's of in reality)

```
{"one Test String to see", "300/1"}
```

How can I do to perform `ToExpression[str]` on the element that contains numbers, and `ToExpression[str, StandardForm, HoldForm]` on the one that is string only?

**UPDATE 2**

To be clear let me bring an example. Let's say I have following string:

```
a = "{a -> some String here, b -> 3/5, c -> {1, 2, 4, 6}}"
(* "{a -> some String here, b -> 3/5, c -> {1, 2, 4, 6}}" *)
```

Now I want to bring this to list of rules to have following output (nothing is code here)

```
{a -> here some String, b -> 3/5, c -> {1, 2, 4, 6}}
```

---

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking.  What output do you expect?  If you want to avoid the sorting due to `Orderless` on `Times` you will need a hold function, e.g. `ToHeldExpression` or `MakeExpression`.  (Or to hide the hold function `ToExpression[str, StandardForm, HoldForm]`.)  However these may still not do what you want, whatever that is, as other kinds of parsing still take place.

Comment: Regarding the update are all the elements of the "string only" part valid Symbols, while the other contains elements that are *not* Symbols?  If so we can use that to separate the types.  If not this needs further clarification.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard In my case only "string only" part needs to be parsed "with hold", the other parts need to be parsed with ToExpression[], since they are only numbers and letters like "2/3 cm" or {1, 2, 3}

Comment: `2/3 cm` contains `cm` which would be parsed as a Symbol; `{1, 2, 3}` would be parsed as a `List`; is this correct?  Please see my comment below the answer also.

Comment: The input shown in **UPDATE 2** is not a String.  Your output is still ambiguous, unless you actually want a bitmap image as output.   Please provide the *real* input and *real* output that you want it to produce.

Comment: It is a list of rules which is actually I want to get as a result.

Comment: Yes, but you did not provide it in *Mathematica* code therefore one cannot tell what parts of it are Strings and what parts are not, etc.

Comment: Updated to the Mathematica code

Comment: This doesn't make sense.  Your **UPDATE 2** now reads as if `a // ToExpression` *is* your solution.  I am sorry but I am going to stop trying to understand this problem.  Perhaps someone else will have an easier time interpreting your needs. :-/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps the closest thing to what you want is to use [`HoldForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldForm.html) to prevent the sorting behavior of `Times` due to [`Orderless`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Orderless.html):

```
str = "one Test String to see";

HoldForm @@ MakeExpression @ str
```

> ```
> one Test String to see
> ```

However it is important to realize that the `HoldForm` head is still present, only that it is not shown in standard formatted output.  Also know that the string *is* still parsed and the string must be valid syntax:

```
HoldForm @@ MakeExpression @ "one Test String to see 2|~+7"
```

> ```
> HoldForm[ErrorBox["one Test String to see 2|~+7"]]
> ```

If your goal is to insert an expression into the Notebook then try:

```
parseString[s_String, prep : (True | False) : True] := 
  FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`UndocumentedTestFEParserPacket[s, prep]]

Cell[parseString[str][[1]], "Input"] // CellPrint
```

> ```
> one Test String to see
> ```

This time that output actually is live code in an Input cell.

`parseString` is a method from John Fultz posted here:

- [How can I get the unchanged Box form of an arbitrary expression?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13317/how-can-i-get-the-unchanged-box-form-of-an-arbitrary-expression/13371#13371)

Related:

- [Passing unquoted strings (poor man's enumeration)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7363/121)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is there a way to have the result not as a code, but as a string. This also doesn't solve Update1, since "3/5" form string will still stay "3/5"

Comment: @SuTron I repeat: it is not clear what you want to do.  `str` *starts* as a string, so how can it be the output also?  Are you trying to evaluate mathematical expressions within a string and replace them in the string with their evaluated forms?